# GLSurfaceView redraw partially like canvas

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I'm developing a game clone of ["Achtung, die kurve"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achtung,_die_Kurve!) where I only need to append small squares to the screen in a fast rate. I previously used canvas were I could reuse the previous image and just append my new squares. I wanted to try using opengl since performance was an issue with SurfaceView and canvas. ("lockCanvas" and "unlockCanvasAndPost" Were to slow.)

Is the same approach possible with OpenGL ES?(Appending squares)  Or do i have to redraw the whole screen every frame?

Or if you have other suggestions of efficient drawing of the "kurves" in the game please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In opengl-es you need to redraw every time but you can always limit it. Add a integer variable and increase it and when it hits over a certain number, say 30, update and draw and reset the counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what your going to have to redraw the screen otherwise the graphics will just trail when they are moved. OpenGL is a much better idea, as long as it is implemented right it will be considerably faster